# How can I pass parameter to ng-click from jsp

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I want to pass parameters to my angular function from jsp.
Normally doing from ng-repeat is easy but in my case I don't know is it possible or not?

this is my code where I get error:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="doTest(<%=my-var%>);">
```

but If I'm doing this code it's working fine:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="doTest('test');">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your variable with quotes:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="doTest('<%=my-var%>');">
//                      here ^  and here ^
```

Without them your variable's value is most likely interpreted as javascript code (not a parameter value).